# How to ensure consistency of data between two execution loops

Tags: c, embedded, task, data-synchronization

I have been developing control software based on FreeRTOS operating system. From the timing point of view the software can be divided into two loops.

The first execution loop (fast loop (FL)) is invoked with period 100 us at the end of analogue-digital conversion. The second execution loop (slow loop (SL)) is invoked after each fourth execution of fast loop. So the timing of the control software can be described by following timing diagram

[image]

I need to ensure consistency of data shared between fast and slow loop. The slow loop has to use during its whole execution time the data values valid at the end of fourth execution of the fast loop.

I have been thinking about how to ensure the above mentioned consistency of data. My first idea is to use some global variable (let´s say `mutex`)

```
typedef enum
{
    SLOW_LOOP_RUNNING,
    SLOW_LOOP_WAITING
}MutexState

MutexState mutex;
```

which will be used in atomic manner. For example in case the slow loop starts its calculation it at first executes

```
mutex = SLOW_LOOP_RUNNING;
```

At the end of slow loop execution it executes

```
mutex = SLOW_LOOP_WAITING;
```

The fast loop monitors always the status of the `mutex` variable and in case it finds out that the mutex contains `SLOW_LOOP_RUNNING` value it doesn´t overwrite the shared variables. I think that this could work but I don´t like the global variable. Does anybody have better idea how to resolve that? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is your operating environment? (eg Linux, a user-process, kernel module); other?

Comment: It sounds as if your program would benefit from DMA instead of polling. What's the reason you must catch every single ADC sample? Is this some manner of signal processing?

Comment: @Lundin, thank you for your reaction. Maybe my expression is clumsy. As I have attempted to describe by the diagram above the values of shared variables used by the SL must not be affected by the FL execution as soon as the SL execution is triggered.

Comment: What am I asking is: what's the actual problem you are trying to solve? Because this looks like a strange solution. Why do you need parallel processing? Why do you need loops? Why do you need 100us deadlines?

Comment: My problem is how to ensure that variables which SL shares with FL have fixed values during SL execution (despite the fact that FL refreshes them the SL has to use the values which were valid at the end of fourth execution of FL). The FL execution period 100 us is coupled with the PWM frequency. As far as the loops. The FL shall implement torque control loop of the induction motor. The SL shall implement other less critical tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is small, I'd just send/copy it. Especially if you're already using `fork()`, you can use [pipes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) ([ex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115862/6069586)). Where your fast loop, on every 4th cycle, can [`write(buf)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) the data to the pipe fd, and the slow loop then [`read(buf)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from it. Even better, if you only want to run the slow loop cycle after you've received data from the 4th fast loop cycle, you can [`select()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to only run the slow loop function when there is data to read from the pipe. This approach, vs mutexes, should be cleaner & less error prone, avoiding the data race entirely; allowing you to treat the slow loop task as a purely functional task.

Comment: Hello JWCS, thank you for your reaction. I like your idea with pipes (queues) but I have been thinking about implementation. My intention is to have the FL and SL to create only the scheduling layer of the software in other words neither FL nor SL don´t know what functions will be executed in them so they don´t know what data will be exchanged between them. This raises a question where the queue should be implemented. In the execution loop "templates" (FL and SL) or in the objects which are executed in them. Thanks in advance for your opinion.

Comment: Well, whichever way you get data from one process to another, in memory it's just a bunch of bytes. You have to specify some kind of common interpretation on both sides, to encode/decode the data. If this is embedded, you're probably not dynamically creating new types of data; if this is for control, then your data is mostly fixed, a priori.